# Is there a way to show message in the actions tab in github actions workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a requirement where I need to print information in the actions tab when the workflow runs is there a way to do that?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this can be done by [writing a Job Summary in your workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#adding-a-job-summary):

[image: Workflow with a job summary]

The simplest way to do that is to append any valid markdown content to the file referenced by the `$GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY` environment variable.

```bash
echo "### Hello world! :rocket:" >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
```

You can do the same thing from PowerShell:

```
"### Hello world! :rocket:" >> $env:GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
```

Or using the `actions/github-script` action:

```
- uses: actions/github-script@v6
  id: my-script
  with:
    result-encoding: string
    retries: 3
    retry-exempt-status-codes: 400,401
    script: |
      core.summary
         .addHeading('Test Results')
         .addCodeBlock(generateTestResults(), "js")
         .addTable([
           [{data: 'File', header: true}, {data: 'Result', header: true}],
           ['foo.js', 'Pass ✅'],
           ['bar.js', 'Fail ❌'],
           ['test.js', 'Pass ✅']
         ])
         .addLink('View staging deployment!', 'https://github.com')
         .write()
```

To attach something like:

[image: Job summary showing fancy tabled results]